# json - Form success message not showing on successful submission with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json, forms

I have difficulty in showing success message on form. Its showing all the error messages but not the success message.

On controller file its showing when I comment $this->model_catalog_outofstockquery->addQuery($this->request->post);
but this line is necessary.

On submitting form the entries are successfully loading to the database.

I have already call model from the constructor

My code on controller file is-

```
    public function write() {
        $this->load->language('product/outofstock_enquiry');

        $json = array();

        if ($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

            if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['name']) < 3) || (utf8_strlen($this->request->post['name']) > 25)) {
                $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_name');
            }
            if (!filter_var($this->request->post['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_email');
            }
            if ((!filter_var($this->request->post['quantity'],FILTER_VALIDATE_INT))) {
                $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_quantity');
            }            

                if (!isset($json['error'])) {            
                $json['success'] = $this->language->get('text_success');
                    $data['product_id'] = $this->request->post['product_id'];
                    $data['product_name'] = $this->request->post['product_name'];
                    $data['name'] = $this->request->post['name'];
                    $data['email'] = $this->request->post['email'];
                    $data['quantity'] = $this->request->post['quantity'];
                    $data['notify'] = 0;
                    $this->model_catalog_outofstockquery->addQuery($this->request->post); 
                }

        }

        $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
        $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
    }
```

The script on the view file under the form is

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
  $('#button-submit').on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'index.php?route=product/outofstock_enquiry/write&product_id=<?php echo $product_id; ?>',
      type: 'post',
      dataType: 'json',
        data: 'name=' + encodeURIComponent($('input[name=\'name\']').val()) + '&email=' + encodeURIComponent($('input[name=\'email\']').val()) + '&product_name=' + encodeURIComponent($('input[name=\'product_name\']').val()) + '&quantity=' + encodeURIComponent($('input[name=\'quantity\']').val()) , 

      data: $("#form-ask").serialize(),
      beforeSend: function() {
        $('#button-submit').button('loading');
      },
      complete: function() {
        $('#button-submit').button('reset');
      },
      success: function(json) {
        $('.alert-success, .alert-danger').remove();

        if (json['error']) {
          $('#outofstock_enquiry').after('<div class="alert alert-danger"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> ' + json['error'] + '</div>');
        }
        if (json['success']) {
          $('#outofstock_enquiry').after('<div class="alert alert-success"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> ' + json['success'] + '</div>');

          $('input[name=\'name\']').val('');
          $('input[name=\'email\']').val('');
          $('input[name=\'product_name\']').val('');
          $('input[name=\'quantity\']').val('');
          $('input[name=\'product_id\']').val('');                      
        }
      } 
    });
  });
//--></script>
```

Comment: On your `success` call; what is the result of `console.log(json);` ?

Comment: its not showing anything in console log

Comment: my assumption is that your ajax dataTypye is set to `json`, but youre treating your results as an array as in `json['error']`.. I may be wrong, but try `json.error` instead.

Comment: And if you check the network tab?

Comment: also, why do you have two `data` parameter options on your `$.ajax` call? is that even correct syntax?

Comment: The form is opening in popup.

Comment: I'd try `json.error` as well. But `console.log(JSON.stringify(json))` ought to show _something_, even if it's an empty object. And the response data in the network tab will give you a clue too. Also, if the page returns anything other than HTTP 200 (success), your code will do nothing - you aren't handling the ajax "error" callback function. And you've defined "data" twice. Not sure what that will do.

Comment: I agree. you should use the `error: function(){ }` option in your ajax to catch any server errors.

Comment: From the point of view of someone who's worked on a JS engine `json.error` doesn't make any difference. His server doesn't produce a `400` status so the error function won't run either. Having two `data` properties is valid syntax, but the second will override the first - meaning that long line of text isn't being sent at all (but that appears to be one of a few errors).

Comment: @LukeBriggs im pretty sure the error function catches more than just `400` error codes. Are you completely sure about that?

Comment: guyz I do php, but not good in scripts.. just using it with some changes.. if ur help can solve it, I'll be grateful.

Comment: @CodeGodie It does catch more than just 400 yes, but my point was that his PHP generates a 200 when returning error JSON (which won't trigger the jQuery error function; as far as it's concerned, everything was fine).

Comment: @ChetanSingh add this option to your $.ajax call: `error: function(a,b,c){ console.log(a);console.log(b);console.log(c); }` Then check your console and let us know what you see.

Comment: @CodeGodie also see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Locqwy6y/) demonstrating those aspects of JS.

Comment: Plz see the console screenshots - 
1 - http://www.alsaceindia.com/err2.jpg

2 - http://www.alsaceindia.com/err1.jpg

Comment: @LukeBriggs Nice. Yes that makes sense.. Guess the array structure shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: @ChetanSingh on this image http://www.alsaceindia.com/err1.jpg, can you click and expand the request on your network tab, show us the full content of that request.

Comment: @CodeGodie Its showing this on chrome 
at eval (<anonymous>)
    at Function.globalEval (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2)
    at n.fn.init.domManip (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:3)
    at n.fn.init.append (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:3)
    at w.appendContent (jquery.magnific-popup.min.js:4)
    at Object.success (jquery.magnific-popup.min.js:4)
    at j (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2)
    at x (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4)

Comment: @CodeGodie & this in Mozilla - 
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user’s experience. For more help http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/  prototype.js:1722:6
Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.  uxcore.en.min.js:16:8001
Use of getAttributeNode() is deprecated. Use getAttribute() instead.  _dist-editor.js:2:27387
SyntaxError: missing : after property id  jquery-2.1.1.min.js:3:6

Comment: @ChetanSingh Quick piece of UX too: `E-Mail` just looks *wrong* to me; it might be more common in your culture though of course. Just "Email" would be more typical.

Comment: this error reflects after adding your given code from jsfiddle

Comment: @ChetanSingh Clicked on the wrong part there; CodeGodie was after the headers/ response (click on the URL/ 'name' instead). That fiddle was just demoing parts of JS - it doesn't strictly "do" anything.

Comment: http://www.alsaceindia.com/err3.jpg

Comment: @ChetanSingh [Like this](https://snag.gy/z5efri.jpg)

Comment: @ChetanSingh im available to help you remotely through Teamviewer if you like. Let me know

Comment: Thanks @CodeGodie please give your email id.. I'll send you my Team Viewer details

Comment: @CodeGodie can u plz give your email Id..

Comment: @ChetanSingh I was waiting.. ended up deleting my message.. let me know when you are available if you still need help.

Comment: @CodeGodie just sent u mail

Comment: @CodeGodie I'm in office had to take permission of my boss.. sorry for the delay

Comment: ah no problem . Just let me know youre ready.

Comment: ah got it. Ok ill connect

Comment: just a little problem in the model file caught by @CodeGodie on Teamviewer
Thanks to him & everyone for their precious time.